# Are there animals that are present in two different classes?

Tags: classification

Are there animals that are present in two different classes, like amphibian and bird, reptile and mammal etc.?

Comment: Like mammals also being vertebrates?

Comment: @WYSIWYG FOR EXAMPLE frog is an amphibian and a mammal (this is not correct it's just an EXAMPLE)..Are there animals present in two different classes?

Comment: @WYSIWYG Wouldn't taxonomist propose a new class if some species (somehow) showed characteristics of 2 close classes?

Comment: Short answer: No. Taxonomy is about categorizing and an organism cannot be placed to different taxa.

Comment: @WYSIWYG Mammals are a class, vertebrates compose a subphylum.

Comment: An organism is not placed into two classes, an amphibia is very different from a mammal. During classification the characters of an organism are considered before it is placed in a particular taxon. You may read ncert class XI biology(the chapters are available online), the concept is explained in the most comprehensible way.

Comment: Classes are a holdover from Linnean classification that don't have any real taxonomic meaning in modern systematics.